# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUBaseAdapter", referenced from:

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

While building unity game for IOS i am getting this error

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUBaseAdapter", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUChartboostAdapter in SUChartboostAdapter(SUChartboostAdapter.o)
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SUAdMobAdapter in SUAdMobAdapter(SUAdMobAdapter.o)

But this frameworks are included in the project.Please give any solution

Steps i did so far:

```
 1.In the project navigator, selected my project.
 2.Selected the target.
 3.Selected the "Build Phases" tab.  Selected the  framework. (optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the "Frameworks"
group.
```

Comment: your library does not support the standard architecture, check once else use the latest SDk

Comment: I already added latest SDk

Comment: check once your SDK supports standard architurure

Comment: i changed standard architectures from arm7 to (arm7,arm64) still not working